# He is going to be reciting the holy religious text

Tags: grammar

> He is going to be reciting the holy religious text.

1. Is 'going' used here intransitively?

2.Is 'going' the main action verb here & 'is' auxiliary verb?

3.Is 'be reciting' gerund?

4.Is 'to' used as preposition here & not as part of infinitive?

5.There is no infinitival clause here, right?

Answer (score 1):

"[Is going to](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/be-going-to)" is a set phrase for the modal verb **will**. '**Recite**' is the main action verb. 'Be reciting' is the progressive tense. So, "**Be going to/will be reciting**" denotes the future progressive tense.